# how to run a ssh reverse tunnel in a startup batch file in background?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

Basically i want to write .bat file in the startup that does a reverse tunnel in the background

So these are the things i tried in the batch file but non worked

```
ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R port1:localhost:port2 user@ip 

ssh -f -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R port1:localhost:port2 user@ip 


start /min cmd.exe /C "ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R port1:localhost:port2 user@ip"   

start /min cmd.exe /C "ssh -f -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R port1:localhost:port2 user@ip"   


start /min cmd.exe /C "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R port1:localhost:port2 user@ip"
```

when i dont include option N and say -f, it doesn't work and i cannot connect from other side

when i do say -fN, weirdly enough (with or without /min) a new empty cmd shell spawns, and even when i close it manually i can still connect! tried killing cmd.exe after a timeout to close it automatically but that didnt work

but there has to be a way, how can i send a reverse ssh tunnel in a batch file without user noticing it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try writing a batch script to run the command at startup. You can refer to https://ss64.com/nt/start.html for more info.
I found a **/B** parameter in it that can solve your problem.

Comment: That doesnt work, when i set /B with or without /MIN it just spawns a CMD with my command written in it, it does connect back but not stealthy